# Заполнить базу данных данными

Tags: sql, plpgsql

Есть три таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE students(
stId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR(64),
secondName VARCHAR(64),
middleName VARCHAR(64));

CREATE TABLE subjects(
sbId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(64));

CREATE TABLE assessments(
assId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
valuation VARCHAR(64),
stId INTEGER REFERENCES students,
sbId INTEGER REFERENCES subjects);
```

Какие есть способы автоматического заполнения таблиц при помощи PL\pgSQL?
Есть ли способ сгенерировать случайне данные(возможно "осмысленные") для таблицы *students* и *subjects*?

Comment: Нет таких. SQL не предназначен для выдумывания данных. Можете воспользоваться существующими справочниками имён-фамилий-отчеств, а предметы взять из учебного плана любого ВУЗа. И рандом в помощь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мое решение. может кому-то пригодится.

```
INSERT INTO subjects (title) VALUES
('Алгебра'), ('Геометрия'), ('Физика'), ('Экономика'), ('Английский'),
('Религия'), ('История'), ('ПТЦА'), ('Радиоматериалы'), 
('Программирование'),
('Метрология'), ('Теория цепей'), ('Компьютерная графика'), ('Цифровые 
 утсройства'), ('Философия'),
('Основы права'), ('Механика'), ('Радиоавтоматика'), ('Социология'), 
('Политология');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_random_students()
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
r record;
studentsCount int;
names VARCHAR[];
secondnames VARCHAR[];
middlenames VARCHAR[];
arr_names_length int;
arr_secondnames_length int;
arr_middlenames_length int;
BEGIN
studentsCount := 0;
names := ARRAY['Сергей', 'Антон', 'Михаил', 'Степан', 'Семен', 
'Николай', 'Василий', 'Виктор', 'Геннадий', 'Александр',
            'Владимир', 'Денис', 'Дмитрий', 'Алексей', 'Константин', 
'Евгений', 'Борис', 'Виталий', 'Станислав', 'Анатолий'];
secondnames := ARRAY['Сергеев', 'Антонов', 'Михаилов', 'Степанов', 
'Семенов', 'Николаевский', 'Васильев', 'Викторов', 'Геннадиев', 
'Александров',
            'Владимирский', 'Денисов', 'Дмитриев', 'Алексеев', 
'Константинов', 'Евгениев', 'Борисов', 'Витальев', 'Станиславский', 
'Анатольев'];
middlenames := ARRAY['Сергевич', 'Антонович', 'Михаилович', 
'Степанович', 'Семенович', 'Николаевич', 'Васильевич', 'Викторович', 
'Геннадьевич', 'Александрович',
            'Владимирович', 'Денисович', 'Дмитриевич', 'Алексеевич', 
'Константинович', 'Евгениевич', 'Борисович', 'Витальевич', 
'Станиславович', 'Анатольевич'];
arr_names_length := array_length(names, 1);
arr_secondnames_length := array_length(secondnames, 1);
arr_middlenames_length := array_length(middlenames, 1);
FOR i IN 1..50000
LOOP
INSERT INTO students (firstName, secondName, middleName) VALUES
(names[trunc(random()*arr_names_length)+1],
secondnames[trunc(random()*arr_secondnames_length)+1],
middlenames[trunc(random()*arr_middlenames_length)+1]);
studentsCount := studentsCount+1;
END LOOP;
RETURN studentsCount;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

SELECT make_random_students();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_random_assessments()
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
student record;
subject record;
assessmentCount int;
BEGIN
assessmentCount := 0;
FOR student IN SELECT * FROM students LOOP
    FOR subject IN SELECT * FROM subjects LOOP
      INSERT INTO assessments (valuation, stId, sbId) VALUES
      (trunc(random()*5)+1, student.stID, subject.sbID);
      assessmentCount := assessmentCount+1;
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;
RETURN assessmentCount;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

SELECT make_random_assessments();
```

Answer (score 2):

Для чисел и дат можно воспользоваться функцией [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html). Для ФИО могу предложить 3 варианта:

1. Заполнять значениями вида Фамилия1, Фамилия2, Фамилия3...
2. Написать свою программу генерации данных, или взять любой текст-рыбу и надергать слов оттуда.
3. Скачать готовую программу. Условно-бесплатных и триальных в интернете хватает. Гуглить по запросу "postgresql генерация данных"